# How to copy attributes from the input CssSel

Tags: scala, lift

```
<lift:sample.render>
<ul class="my_ul">
<li class="my_li"><sample:data /></li>
</ul>
</lift:sample.render>

// expected result is
<ul class="my_ul">
<li class="my_li">Data 1</li>
<li class="my_li">Data 2</li>
<li class="my_li">Data 3</li>
</ul>
<ul class="my_ul">
<li class="my_li">Data 4</li>
<li class="my_li">Data 5</li>
<li class="my_li">Data 6</li>
</ul>
<ul class="my_ul">
<li class="my_li">Data 7</li>
<li class="my_li">Data 8</li>
<li class="my_li">Data 9</li>
</ul>
......
```

1. I want to keep the attributes, so that the elements can display normal
2. how can I generate data as above, given the source data is a list of String. (List[String]("data 1", "data 2", ...))
3. Implement with LiftSnippet or CssSel

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do here.  What is the logic regarding where one unordered list stops and the next begins?  Is it a list of x values and you want to display them 3 at a time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def simple.render(source:List[String]) = {
  ".my_ul *" #> source.group(4).map(sub => ".my_li *" #> sub) 
}
```